# How to configure Cognos users authentication with sql database?

Tags: java, cognos

Can any one please help about custom database configuration for authentication sources in cognos? I have found article for flat file and LDAP as authentication source but not able to find how to set my sql server database as authentication source in cognos reporting.

Comment: There are 7 out of the box authentication providers cognos supports.  LDAP is one... you should authenticate with the LDAP server directly.  If you want to use one that is not supported, they have a Custom Authentication Provider option, which requires you to set one up in the SDK.  There are instructions and examples available from IBM.